# CTRL+C doesn't help qutting "at" utility prompt. How to safely quit?

Tags: command-line, at-command

I ran the following code and when I reached the second heredoc I became stuck in an at prompt (see image below). How to safely quite from this (without braking anything)?

The code:

```
bash /dev/fd/40 40<< 'PMA'

cat << PMA_UNINSTALL | at 'now + 2 minutes'

phpdismod mcrypt mbstring 
apt-get purge phpmyadmin -y
service apache2 restart
sed -i 's/Include \/etc\/phpmyadmin\/apache.conf/ /g' /etc/apache2/apache2.conf

PMA_UNINSTALL

PMA
```

The promot:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> (or <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + some key near to <kbd>Z</kbd>), brought me back to Bash.

Comment: After that, you may want to run `jobs` to see what was suspended.

Comment: Because you suspended the command, not exited it.

Comment: How did I suspend it?... I just ran the code in the question. Nothing more.

Answer (score 4):

The quit the `at` prompt, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> on a new line:

```
$ at now
warning: commands will be executed using /bin/sh
at> echo "hi"
at> <EOT>
job 6 at Sun Jan  1 20:20:00 2017
```

The `<EOT>` is printed by `at` on pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>D</kbd>.

Comment: EOT meaning End Of  Transmission

Comment: I hit Return, and then combining Ctrl+d but nothing happens.

Comment: @Benia give a verifiable example - for the pic you show, there's no prompt, and the code snippet you give causes bash to segfault on my system after I type `PMA`.